# actionscript 3, add a watermark to image and save

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, watermark, swfloader

my task -

1. Open a picture from computer
2. Add the watermark in the corner
3. Ask a request to download  edited image back to computer

how is it possible?

- general image - jpg.
- watermark- it does not matter. Use all what you want

Comment: Which one of these 3 steps are you struggling with? There are tutorials via web search for loading/saving images with AS3, for watermark make a new `sprite` then `addChild` the image first (so it's put on bottom layer) then next `addChild` the watermark (it will now be on top of image). To control watermark's x/y pos use for example `mySprite.myWatermark.x = 50` etc...

Answer (score 1):

1. Opening and saving files: [FileReference class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html). See `FileReference.browse()` and `FileReference.save()`. Note: you can only open or save files upon user interaction (i.e. user presses a button, you open the OS browse dialog).
2. The bitmap you load is represented by [BitmapData class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html). When you have a picture and a watermark image, you can `draw` the latter on the former using [BitmapData.draw()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw()).
3. Use `FileReference.save()` as pointed out in 1.